# Grid of cards from 4 to 3 on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I need to transform my grid of cards, so on mobile devices it only fits 3 in the width of the mobile device, but 4 on desktop and tablets.

Right now I have this:

[image]

But won't resize properly so I cannot make the screen narrower (to a mobile device size):

[image]

**CodePen**:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/abNQXLg

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="row">
    <p> Just spacing</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <section id="team">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="grid">
            
                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" alt="Avatar"
                                    style="width:120px;height:120px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <br />
                                <p>WR : 50%</p>
                                <p>PR : 50%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
                <input value="1" type="range" max="4" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
                <datalist id="ticks2">
                    <option value="1">Very bad</option>
                    <option value="2">Bad</option>
                    <option value="3">Good</option>
                    <option value="4">Excellent</option>
                </datalist>
                <output class="__range-output-square"></output>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"
                    checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                    Default radio
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                    Second default radio
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3"
                    disabled>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                    Disabled radio
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Using suggested media queries, don't work:

[image]

Code edited:

```
 /* Tablets */
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 15px;
  }
}

/* Mobile  */
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using media queries to achieve your desired result.

```
<!-- Tablets -->
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  } 
}

<!-- Mobile -->
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  } 
}
```

This is how your final CSS should look

```
   .grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
     justify-items: center;
     align-items: center;
     grid-gap: 15px;
    }

   .flip-card {
     border-style: hidden;
     background-color: transparent;
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
    perspective: 1000px;
   }

   .flip-card-inner {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     transition: transform 0.6s;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }

    .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

   .flip-card-front,
   .flip-card-back {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .flip-card-front {
     background-color: #bbb;
     color: black;
   }

   .flip-card-back {
     background-color: #222e36ef;
     color: white;
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

 @media(max-width: 768px) {
   .grid {
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
   } 
 }

 @media(max-width: 500px) {
   .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
   } 
 }
```

[image: Tablet view works]

[image: Mobile view works]

Comment: Suggested code, didn't work , not even on codepen. I've added the rest of the properties of the grid class, besides grid-template-columns. I'll post an update on my original question.

Comment: Hey, that's not the way you can use media queries as you have at the moment. Please leave everything the same as it was before you changed it and add my specified media queries as I have written at the end of your CSS. Media queries are separate from the rest of the CSS and don't go on a class you've written out for web layout, because then you are altering your web layout :) That's why we specify Tablet and Mobile because it's separate! Let me know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I see, I thought I had to replace my grid class.  What about below answer? Can we only use the media query for max-width 768 alone? What are the differences?

Comment: Technically you can use 768px for everything. What it means is it captures devices with a screen width of 768px and below. Practically I tend to use tablets and mobile separately because I want my page to look different on each device. For example, 3 columns are great on a tablet but on a mobile device in portrait layout that might make the information look too crammed and I'd rather use a single column thus making use of the screen width so I want to specify that below the media 768x with the media 500px.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comment in above answer should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/68cwt19m/

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  } 
}
```

Comment: "above" answer can change — answers move around as they get votes.